# May one purchase smoothies anywhere?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, food

What do sources say about purchasing smoothies at places with no kosher certification? Would this be allowed?

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of potential issues with [smoothies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothie)

- **the milk or yoghurt**: which might or might not be *chalav Israel* for those who pay attention to this
- **fruit**: particularly strawberries or raspberries commonly contain insects: however since they are crushed ou pureed this is not an issue (see [here](http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/halacha/Issue10.pdf) from R Moishe Dovid Lebovits)
- **other fruit juices used** if any: they would need to be kosher, with a particular issue with grape juice if handled by non-Jews
- any **supplements** (Wikipedia: sweeteners, whey powder, plant milk, nuts, nut butter, seeds, tea, chocolate, herbal supplements, or nutritional supplements) would need a reliable *hekhsher*
- **the blender:** in case it is used to blend other non-kosher beverages and not cleaned well
- **sitting down in a non-kosher restaurant** (see e.g., [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/89242/11501)): although you are maybe asking about only purchasing a drink which is [permitted by some](https://dinonline.org/2011/09/13/drink-at-non-kosher-restaurant/)

**So, in summary** a cold smoothie prepared on dedicated or clean equipment, with no or kosher supplements, might be permitted if prepared with water, kosher fruit juice or, for someone not particular about *chalav Israel*, milk.

Of course, [consult your rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146)
before implementing anything [you learn here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1734).

Comment: #2 is controversial. The local kashrus here holds that you can’t use uncertified raspberries because of the bugs; even though they’re being ground up, the person making the smoothie is doing it on your behalf, so it’s an issue of אין מבטלין איסור לכתחילה.

Comment: @donielF the issue with blending raspberries is if the reason they are being blended is to crush the bugs to become batel then it is a problem of an mevatal litchatchilla but a smoothie which is blended whether there are bugs or not and it isn't known 100% that there are in fact bugs should not be an issue bc the intended purpose is to make the item

Comment: @Dude I understand the logic behind the opinion that it’s okay, all I’m saying is that there’s an opinion that argues.

Answer (score -1):

As long as the utensils are clean, and everything else is kosher, you can go to juice n Java for only a smoothie. Though if you do want to go to a none kosher place, some will advise due to(merit ayin) to be discreet about. If you’re on an island and see coconuts with a straw, it’s fine.

Please note, even though it’s not under smoothies,  please look at the kosher Starbucks website, into the regular coffee, as not all regular coffees are kosher there, I know I was taken by surprise too.

As a former mashgiach for the ORB of south Florida.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/46163)